# Dynamicaly changing ng-pattern regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to changing regex pattern by same rules. Example is in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z6WaO6V4v6ZUcdPDdnCV?p=preview)

If is selected type, which have regular expression, model is updated, if value is valid. But if is selected type, which doesn't have regular expression (e.g. 'string' in my code), model is never updated. Doesn't matter, if function returned *null* or *empty string*.

My question is, if exist way, how turn this validation off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `.*` when you want to allow any input:

```
$scope.getValidatorRegex = function () {
      switch ($scope.type) {
          case 'int':
            return /^\d+$/;
          default:
            return /.*/;
      }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in my example, but in my real code not. I also tried `.*`, but I have now found, that my source code in TypeScript don't translate into javascript, that's why all my changes don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your fields in a `<form>` tag to initiate the angulars built-in validation. See [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController)

When you do that, the `int` validation will work, but since numbers can also be strings, your string validation won't work.